# How to start two geth instances (console and mist)

Tags: go-ethereum

Once I start mist I can't start run geth on terminal. It says

> "Error starting protocol stack: listen udp :30303: bind: address
>   already in use"

or

> "Fatal: Error starting protocol stack: resource temporarily
>   unavailable".

Is it possible to run two geth as one time?